# Редактирование Event Trigger через код C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

[image: Снимок]

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как через код на c# заполнить данные поля и выбрать функцию. Перелистал все и вся, но не нашёл ответа.
п.с. код не предоставляю так как просто его НЕТ, а если был бы не задавал вопрос :)

Comment: А в эдиторе чем не устраивает обработчики назначить? Вы хотите странного, скорее всего по незнанию. А что на самом деле нужно и зачем, не говорите.

Comment: Вопрос не как сделать определённую логику, а как можно решить данный вопрос. Остальное не вижу смысла описывать

Comment: Ок, если кратко, то никак, не предусмотрено движком.

Comment: Спасибо |C
Но думаю что все же есть какой то да способ

Comment: То что вы хотите имеет смысл только при динамической/рефлексивной генерации кода. То есть тогда, когда на момент компиляции вы не знаете, сколько, где и каких у вас функций в скриптах. Предполагая, что ваша игра не пишет сама себе код во время работы, можно понять, что вам не нужно это. Вам нужно не это, а что именно нужно - вы не видите смысла описывать. Мы в тупике.

Comment: Если это не решить как вы говорите, что это не предусмотренно, то я сам найду другой путь :) Так как вариантов решения я видел изначально несколько, просто решил пойти этим путём, и тут встал в тупик. Но за доп. знания спасибо

Comment: Понял, успехов.